# How do I grab any segment from URL using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL : `http://localhost:8080/school/teacher/reports/chapter-quiz/student`

Getting the last segment, I just need to do this

`var lastSegment = location.pathname.split('/').pop();`

But how do I grab the one next to the last one ? **chapter-quiz**

Comment: Can't you just `pop()` twice?

Comment: Maybe this [old fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tive/LjbPq/) of mine can help you

Answer (score 4):

I'd say something like this?

```
var segments      = location.pathname.split('/');
secondLastSegment = segments[segments.length - 2];
```

Answer (score 2):

## Split the segments

`var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );`

---

## Create Variables

- `var segment_1 = pathArray[1];`
- `var segment_2 = pathArray[2];`
- `var segment_3 = pathArray[3];`
- `var segment_4 = pathArray[4];`

---

## Use it

`console.log(segment_4) --> chapter-quiz`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
var t = window.location.pathname.split("/")
t.pop();
t.pop();
t.pop();
```